# Thanos link is missing in the source when the alert triggers in Prometheus stack v43.2.0

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, thanos

Thanos link is missing in the **source ** when the alerts are triggered in Opsgenie.

Example:
**Source**: /graph?g0.expr=%281+-+absent%28kube_pod_status_ready%7Bcondition%3D%22true%22%2Cnamespace%3D%22tps-obelix%22%2Cpod%3D~%22.%2Acid-operator.%2A%22%7D%29%29+or+sum%28kube_pod_status_ready%7Bcondition%3D%22true%22%2Cnamespace%3D%22tps-obelix%22%2Cpod%3D~%22.%2Acid-operator.%2A%22%7D%29+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1

This is the expected result. The source should point to thanos link for example:

Source: /graph?g0.expr=%281+-+absent%28kube_pod_status_ready%7Bcondition%3D%22true%22%2Cnamespace%3D%22tps-obelix%22%2Cpod%3D~%22.%2Acid-operator.%2A%22%7D%29%29+or+sum%28kube_pod_status_ready%7Bcondition%3D%22true%22%2Cnamespace%3D%22tps-obelix%22%2Cpod%3D~%22.%2Acid-operator.%2A%22%7D%29+%3D%3D+0&g0.tab=1

Environment:
The source url used to work in prometheus stack version: 41.7.3. but not showing in version: 43.2.0. Also, we have checked that web external url is properly configured in

```
    - name: prometheus
      args:
        - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml'
        - '--storage.agent.path=/prometheus'
        - '--enable-feature=agent'
        - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
        - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
        - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
        - '--web.external-url=<thanos url>'
        - '--web.route-prefix=/'
        - '--web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web_config/web-config.yaml'
```

Tried by removing the --web.external-url= parameter or hardcoding the expected value of thanos url did not resolve the issue.